# Is using Viewbag for remembering past form inputs a bad idea?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a small asp.net core mvc application that basically consists of a form that a user can input some constraints into, and then get a filtered list of data depending on those constraints.

The controller action for filtering data basically looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Query(QueryModel query)
{


    var customers = await _context.Customers.AsQueryable().FilterCustomerList(query);
    

    return View("Index", customers);
}
```

Now, my issue is that I would like the inputs in the fields to persist after entering them and being redirected to the view again. Right now they are currently just reset.

One way of doing this that I found was using viewBag. An example for a single query attribute is this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Query(QueryModel query)
{

    var customers = await _context.Customers.AsQueryable().FilterCustomerList(query);
    ViewBag.Name = query.Name;


    return View("Index", customers);
}
```

and then the inpuit html elelment would look like:

```
                    <div class="col-md-4">

                        <input name="Name" type="text" placeholder="First name" value="@ViewBag.Name"class="form-control">
    
                    </div>
```

And this makes sure that if something has been entered into a field, it will now be entered into the field when after the query has been submitted.

But when I read up on ViewBag, I understand that a lot of .net developers have an aversion to it. It's not safe, the compiler can't catch errors in it easily etc.

Also, If I were to add all the input fields in my form to the viewbag, I would need a lot of lines of `ViewBag.Attribute = query.SomeAttribute` (20-30). Which seems like a code-smell too.

Is there any nicer way to do what I am trying to here?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included your `QueryModel` class and that class could be a key point to a cleaner approach.

You see, usually the user data, POSTed to your action is bound to the model, from there it's rendered on the form and is POSTed again. The model binding is where an input of a specific name is bound to a model member of the same name.

Thus, there's no need for viewbags.

More formally:

The Model

```
public class QueryModel
{
    [your-validators-in-attributes, e.g. Required or MaxLength 
     there can be multiple validators]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The controller:

```
[HttpPost]
async Task<IActionResult> Query(QueryModel query)
{
    // query.Name is there, bound from the view
}
```

The View:

```
@model .....QueryModel

<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.Name, new { placeholder = "a placeholder" } )
</div>
```

The html helper does two things

- renders an input of the given name (`Name` in this case)
- sets its value depending on the actual value from the model

In newer ASP.NETs you can achieve similar result by using *tag helpers*, where instead of `Html.TextBoxFor(...)` you write

```
<input asp-for="Name" />
```

These two approaches, using html helpers or using tag helpers are equivalent. In both cases there's no need for view bags.

Comment: thank! so since my current model is List<CustomerModel>, I should now return perhaps return a tuple of (QueryModel, List<Customer>)?

Comment: No, make a class that contains List<Customer> as a field but has other fields as well.